# How to get URL Scheme myapp:// to work with Instagram API redirect uri

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm new to mobile development.

I have an app that has Instagram Authentication.

My URL scheme is working. When I open Safari and type `myapp://` it opens the app.

When I try to add `myapp://` as the redirect URL in Instagram API it errors and says `Enter a valid website`.

How do I get this redirect URL to work? What should I have as Instagrams redirect URI?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm stuck in this as well. Still thinking another workaround.... Instagram now only accept the url with http prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this problem is only with ios, not android because in android we can save a url scheme like this: `http://myApp` in AndroidManifest.xml file which is a valid redirect url in instagram form at https://www.instagram.com/developer/
For ios, we need something like this: `http//myApp://`, which works fine in safari, but isn't a valid url in instagram form
In my case, following was the state of my app when I faced a similar problem:

- I was using [Linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) api of react-native to open instagram login page in browser;
- After submitting the form with proper login credentials, I could see a new page hit in the browser with access_token, something like this: `http://myApp/#access_token=asa2dcc...'`
- But then it never redirected back to my app from browser

So, I was able to get the token, but it wasn't automatically redirecting back to my app.So I handled this redirecting part manually as following:

- First of all, I used [WebView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html) api of react-native rather than `Linking`;What it does is it opens a web view in your app rather than in a browser so you can have full control of navigation within the app
- I didn't add any redirect url for ios on instagram/developer site, the one I added for android was enough
- The key to solving this problem was getting this [prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#onnavigationstatechange) in which I can get the url with access_token so that it can be fetched out and used for further api calls
- I used [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop#navigate-Link-to-other-screens) to navigate to the screen with WebView and also passed a callback which would receive a token which in turn can be used to make other api calls:

  ```
  navigation.navigate('InstaWebView', {
    callback: (err, access_token) => {
      if (!access_token) { 
        return Alert.alert('Error in fetching insta token');
      }
      // make api calls
    },
  });
  ```
- `InstaWebView` component returned following WebView from the render function:

  ```
  <WebView
        ref={WEBVIEW_REF}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        onNavigationStateChange={
            this.onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)
        }
        source={{ uri: instaUrl }}
        onError={() => {
          Alert.alert('Error in loading WebView..Please try again');
          return navigation.goBack();
        }}
      />
  ```

Have a look at [this code](https://github.com/defining-technology/react-native-backbutton/blob/master/index.ios.js) for more help

Hope this helps someone!